# Kinda new to programming and got some questions

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

i just signed up to this site, and im kinda new to programming, so im gonna need help,i downloaded android studio and i've got a couple of questions:
 1. sometimes i cant move a button or a textview freely wherever i want, what may be the problem? (not sure how to divide the layouts well btw)
 2. how to make a button transparent?(I made my own background with designed sign in button, now i wanna place a button above that sign in button pic that i made and make it transparent)
3.i have a project at school to make an app with web service, i have to add a working sign up and sign in button for anyone who'd like to sign, if you have any tips or video tutorials i can use that'd be awesome!

Sorry for long post, i really wanna master programming and making this new step
Thanks a ton :D

Comment: The purpose of the forum is to answer _specific_ coding questions. For the questions about the layout, include the xml code. I highly recommend you read the android introductory training, then consider your questions again.  http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

In xml:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem on not being able to move the buttons,textviews,etc, was probably because of the parent layout you are using.Are you using Relative Layout?Relative layout positions widgets according to the previous widget.For example you drag a textview in the middle of the screen,then you add another below it. The next time you move any of these two, the other would move according to the distance you previously put it with the other widget.Try converting it to a Linear layout(can be vertial or horizontal), where your widgets are aligned horizontally or vertically.Just a tip, you can put a layout inside another layout,and this personally makes it easier for me to position things :) hope this helped.